# Azure Application Gateway slash termination uri path

Tags: azure, uri, reverse-proxy, gateway, azure-application-gateway

I'm using Azure Application Gateway, I've a strange trouble.
The Gateway works for URL similar to: `https://www.example.com/resoruce/`
It doesn't work for URL similar to: `https://www.example.com/resoruce`

So, I have to terminate the URL with a `"/"`.

Can you help me?
Thanks,

Comment: I have the same issue with my set-up and it appears that gateway tries to add a trailing slash when there is one missing, resulting in an extra redirect. There is a hint about this behavior (and potential solution) in the link below, although I still see the same old behavior even if they claim to have removed the default redirect.

https://github.com/Azure/application-gateway-kubernetes-ingress/issues/458